# Mysql Multiplying and adding Result of Subquery

Tags: mysql

Hi I am new to my sql I am trying to multiply and add the result of my subquery however my query is not working it gives me 0 output always for each rows

my column is like this Output of total column is wrong

```
Val1       Income    Val2     Total
1            5        5        0  
1            1        8        0
1            1        7        0
5            7        6        0
```

my query is like this

```
SELECT  

 COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) AS 'Val1',


    (SELECT SUM(CAST(COALESCE(r.t_payment_total,0) AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AS 'Income'
FROM reserv r
INNER JOIN newtbladds1 t ON t.t_parent_id = r.id
 WHERE r.t_status!="Pending" && r.t_status!="Booked" AND r.c_mid = m.id AND  t.t_type_id = t1.t_type_id 
 )AS 'Income',

 num1 AS 'Val2',

 'Val1'*'Income'+ 'Val2' as 'Total'



 FROM tbladds1 t1
JOIN tbladds1_type tt ON tt.id = t1.t_type_id
JOIN tbladdress m ON m.id = t1.t_mid
JOIN tbladdressfr mf ON mf.id = t1.t_floor_id
JOIN tblppl mp ON mp.t_mid = m.id AND mp.t_type = 'try' AND mp.t_system_id = 'ok'
GROUP BY t1.t_tool_type_id
ORDER BY m.t_m ASC, tt.t_ttype ASC, mf.t_floor ASC;
```

Desired Output is like this. I will really appreciate any help or advice Thank you

```
Val1       Income    Val2     Total
1            5        5        10
1            1        8        8
1            1        7        7
5            7        6        41
```

Comment: rather than the subquery, can you `JOIN reservr ... JOIN newtlbadds1` and rely on the `GROUP BY` to add up the payment. Its really hard to determine the column names not quantified with a table name.

Comment: Why isn't total 9 and 8, in the second and third row, respectively ?